# MYSQL Issue With DISTINCT SUM

Tags: php, mysql, sum, distinct, report

We have a 'report generator', which basically builds a series of mysql queries based on options selected by the user.  Data from the series of queries is used to draw a graph.  We've run across a report that is returning incorrect values, based on SUM.  Here is the query (I'm not sure if there is code formatting on this site, so I will just paste it):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM( pp.EffectivePrice)
FROM quotes qu
LEFT JOIN plans pl ON pl.ID = qu.planID AND qu.active_quote = '1'
LEFT JOIN plan_procedures pp ON pp.QuoteID = qu.ID AND qu.active_quote = '1'
LEFT JOIN patients pt ON pt.ID = pl.patientID
LEFT JOIN events_log el7881 ON el7881.TreatmentID = pl.ID
LEFT JOIN events_log el9205 ON el9205.TreatmentID = pl.ID
WHERE  el7881.LogDate >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00'  AND ( (el7881.CurrStageID != '5'  AND pt.ID != '')  AND  (el7881.CurrStageID != '19'  AND pt.ID != '') ) AND  (((CAST(pl.surgery_date AS DATE)  BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-31' AND pl.surgery_date != '') OR (pl.LastSurgeryDate != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND CAST(pl.LastSurgeryDate AS DATE)  BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-01-31 23:59:59'))  AND pt.ID != '')  AND  el9205.LogDate <= '2011-01-31 23:59:59'  AND ( (el9205.CurrStageID = '4' AND el9205.PrevStageID != '4'  AND pt.ID != '') ) AND  qu.active_quote = '1'  AND ( pl.doctorID = '6'  OR  pl.doctorID = '9'  OR  pl.doctorID = '13' )
```

The query is automatically generated by the php script, so it is convoluted.  But the question here is simple:  Why, when I run this query, is the resulting value different than when I run the same query without 'SUM()', and just manually add the values up?  When I add them manually, the result is correct, but the result with 'SUM()' is higher than it should be.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT DISTINCT returns only unique rows. Your query, even though it is highly involved, only returns a single row with a single field when you use the SUM() version.

When you do `SELECT DISTINCT pp.EffectivePrice`, you're eliminating any rows which happen to have the same EffectivePrice value.

so, given some fake return data of

```
   $1.00
   $2.00
   $1.00
   $3.00
```

the DISTINCT will hide the duplicate $1.00 result, and your sum will be $1 + $2 + $3 = $6, which is now short by $1 from the actual total.

Answer (score 0):

When you select using DISTINCT, you get distinct values. Any doubles are removed. So, if your query without DISTINCT would return: `1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 6`

then using DISTINCT would make it return `1, 3, 4, 5, 6`.

You used DISTINCT outside of the SUM, therefor, all numbers, including doubles, are added up, and then you get the DISTINCT values of the result, which is already one number. In other words, DISTINCT doesn't do anything in your query.

Now, if you would do: `SELECT SUM(DISTINCT pp.EffectivePrice)`, then you would add up all *distinct* prices.

But actually, that may not be right as well. Are you sure you don't want the sum of the total? I think you shouldn't use DISTINCT at all.

Comment: Strangely removing DISTINCT gives me the exact same result (too high). Moving DISTINCT within the SUM(), on the other hand, gives a much smaller value than is expected.  I don't get it.

Comment: Removing DISTINCT will give you the same value as I explained. Moving DISTINCT inside the SUM gives you the sum of the distinct values. If you do that, it should give you the same result as if you only had DISTINCT, without SUM, and added up the values yourself.